# How do I refer to existing footnotes inside a caption?

Tags: captions, footnotes

I have a footnote in my latex text that that I am reusing a lot. [This article on texfaq.org](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-repfootnote) helped me how to do that. However, sometimes I need to refer to the same footnote within, e.g., a figure caption. Latex document example:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{My text}

Here is text\footnote{Footnote: blah\dots} \\
Here is more text\footnote{\label{fn:info} Footnote: blah blah\dots}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    % \caption{Important remark\footref{fn:repeat}} %% With footref
    \caption{Important remark\footnotemark[\ref{fn:info}]} %% With footnoteremark
    \label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This seems to not work that great. Using `\footnoteremark` yields:

> Argument of @caption has an extra }.

If I try using a `\footref` (using the "footmisc" package), I get:

> Missing \endcsname inserted.

Comment in/put the "caption" lines in the example to see the different outputs. How can I use any of these commands inside captions? If I had to choose, I'd prefer an answer for `\footref`, as I found that to be neater. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem!

Comment: @Zarko Added MWE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear, what is your problem. Solution with commented caption work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section*{My text}

Here is text\footnote{Footnote: blah\dots} \\
Here is more text\footnote{\label{fn:info} Footnote: blah blah\dots}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Important remark \footref{fn:info}.} %% With footnoteremark
    \label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

*Note*: package `hyperref` had to be loaded last (with rare exception)- Above MWE produce:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that last remark made the trick: you really _have to_ load the hyperref package last. Then it worked. Don't know what to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special in principle to refer to a footnote. You can simply include a `\label` in the footnote and refer to it using `\ref` in the caption of the figure. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Label in caption}

\lipsum*[2]\footnote{A footnote not related to any figure.}

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{\label{fnInfo} Important information that can be used by different figures.}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{See footnote \ref{fnInfo} for details.}
\label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. Yes, it sure works, but from a stylistic POV, I'd prefer solving this by using actual (superscripted) footnote references.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by @Zarko pointed out what the issue was (package loading order), the answer by @Andre inspired me to create my own solution that worked fine.

`\newcommand{\reffootnote}[1]{$^{\scriptsize \textrm{\ref{#1}}}$}`

This creates a command that takes a ref, formats the size and superscripts it. It works anywhere and is quite simple.